# http request with multiple ranges returning HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Tags: http, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse, http-get

I'm sending an http request to a server that requests an image but using range header with several ranges, the request text is:

```
GET /images/nav_logo102.png HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com.eg
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Cookie: PREF=ID=8aacc11c670a5a37:U=cba349de64cbf880:FF=0:LD=en:TM=1310392358:LM=1327944471:S=zc8_vfTdF5U3C-XN; NID=56=15iHWUMVXBGpdEkEcMCeu32GUL6GlK3aEB5vmocRT4kdILhwGpe9mn6DqDrnZBYWJzA2g4YzfXP8IP3tH7Hw4CzC6FwDrV3uqgv3XhCqmrWI0TBD52Vs3nbdth5YzkOR; SID=DQAAAMUAAAC5feWAhXsCT9NT6ObU32dOLBTU_KtRzxc7Ug6QWIhQW_bpXNvzQtoddtt-a2BbUefv89ZjwNwgrgCiCse3INYkeCyfR7PVPaoDPEmUWQ_0sHXBgbf5U0JBg0XxT8KZMmY9kLOZfEKGg0UGtfNNk8uJKWwPXWlkCYjGalQFyVinUNwiYqayYHGvnA0vtiftBCgqnpHawkyVWoo9hCk3vfDKrRHSdO-GQZoxbL21VlH2dbsJJrnJBaVlR-y8KTg14eLgYpt2swZJxcVZwHThhaF-; HSID=AJLTtk1qkIE6L4aLe; GZ=Z=1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Range: bytes=2048-4095,4096-6143,6144-8191,8192-10239,10240-12287,12288-14335,14336-16383,16384-18431,18432-20479,20480-22527,22528-24575,24576-26623,26624-26722
```

but the server is responding with

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

and sending the whole image
if i try the same thing but with only one range, it works and i get only the requested range.
any idea how the request should be made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add \r\n\r\n after last header.

REQUEST:

```
GET /images/djsBox_2.jpg HTTP/1.1\r\n
Range: bytes=0-2,10-20\r\n
Host: www.djsoft.net\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
\r\n
```

I checked it with [WFetch](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21625) tool, and the response is `HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content\r\n`

And the server actually returned 2 parts of data:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n
Content-Length: 196\r\n
Content-Type: multipart/byteranges; boundary=4b9e42cd78baa9\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
--4b9e42cd78baa9\r\n
Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n
Content-range: bytes 0-2/4543\r\n
\r\n
яШя\r\n
--4b9e42cd78baa9\r\n
Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n
Content-range: bytes 10-20/4543\r\n
\r\n
\x000\x001\x001\x001\x000`\x000`\x000\x000я\r\n
--4b9e42cd78baa9--\r\n
```

Comment: I already have \r\n\r\n after the last header ... its just not shown here due to the "code sample" formatting

Comment: Well, if all your ranges add up to a whole file, the resulting code will be 200. What happens of you leave only 2 first ranges?

Comment: its the same, i even tried Range: bytes=0-0,-1 which is used as an example from the http 1.1 standard, but i get the same result

Comment: do you have an example request you can show me that has multiple ranges requested? all i can find only contain one range

Comment: I found that sometimes the server responds with HTTP/1.1 200 and sometimes with HTTP/1.1 206 I don't know why this happens .. but its happening even if i'm requesting the same file